# How to write correct app.get()? (node.js / express / boby-parser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I create server (node.js / express / boby-parser)

and I need to get array of objects 'users'.
its part of code from server.js file:

```
let users = [{
    name: 'user1',
}];

app.get('/users/', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(pth.dir, 'build', 'index.html');
    res.json(users);
    res.sendFile(filePath);
});
```

Its my code from frontend:

```
const handleResponse = (response) => {
    return response.text().then(text => {
        const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
        if (!response.ok) {
            const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
        return data;
    });
};

const getAll = (baseUrl) =>  {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET'
    };
    return fetch(baseUrl, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
};
```

Something wrong with my code at server. (I just dodnt know how to use express server).
when I use getAll function I got JSON text replace my page. Can anyone help? How should I write app.get() in server.js.  Or do I need write in server part one app.get() to get page or another app.get() to get JSON data?

Comment: You're trying to send two different responses.  One is JSON data, the other is a file.  You can only send one response.  Which one do you want to send?

Comment: So to get page from adress '/users/' and to get JSON from adress '/users/' I need somehow to write two different app.get()?

Comment: If you want to provide two entirely different responses then the client would have to make two different requests to get those responses.  You can often combine data (such as JSON or XML) into a single larger response object, but responding with both JSON and a file isn't going to work, the content types are entirely different.  A browser or any standard client wouldn't know what to do with that mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to send a file in the response?:

```
res.sendFile(filePath);
```

For starters, the response content can either be JSON *or* a file (or any of a variety of other things of course), but not both.  With data like JSON or XML it's possible to combine multiple objects into one larger object for a single response, but this won't work if the content types are entirely different as it is with a file.

Looking at your client-side code, you're not even doing anything with that file.  You only read the JSON data:

```
return response.text().then(text => {
    const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
    if (!response.ok) {
        const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
    return data;
});
```

So the simplest approach here would just be to not try to send back the file:

```
app.get('/users/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(users);
});
```

**Edit:** Based on comments below, you seem to be struggling with the different requests the client makes to the server.  The browser loading the page is one request with one response.  If that page includes JavaScript that needs to fetch data, that would be a separate AJAX request with its own response containing just that data.

It’s possible to use JSON (or any data) server-side to populate a page template and return a whole page with the data.  For that you’d need to use (or build) some kind of templating engine in the server-side code to populate the page before returning it.

Comment: thank you. But when I change my app.get() to this - ```app.get('/users/', (req, res) => {res.json(users);});``` I got only blank page with JSON text instead of my users page.  I use 'react-router-dom' and I use this path to show users page... ```<Route path="/users" component={Users} />``` So do I need create anothe path to get Json data? `/usersData/` for example.

Comment: @WillBlack: What is the goal here?  Are you trying to return JSON data?  A file?  A web page?  In your client-side code you only read the JSON data, so where are you even trying to open a file or web page?

Comment: I got page, /users/ and i need get Joson data to show users at this page

Comment: @WillBlack: *”I need to get JSON data”* - Then what’s the problem?  In your previous comment you indicated that it’s successfully returning the JSON data, which is what you want (and what your client-side code expects).  Can you clarify specifically why you think it’s not working?

Comment: when I get data it replace my page and I see only JSON text not page with users. or when I returt file ```res.sendFile(filePath);``` I see page but can't read JSON data.

Comment: all i want to know is how return page and get json for that page at the same time... may be I need two app.get() function. sorry I just heavent  any experience in express server.

Comment: @WillBlack: *”it replace my page”* - Then that’s what you’re doing wrong.  The code which does that isn’t in the question, but basically don’t do that.  You’re just fetching data, not an entirely new page.  (If you want to navigate to a new page then you wouldn’t need AJAX in the first place.)  Just use the data to update the current page’s UI.  Or, if you need to get a whole new page, then do basically the opposite of this answer... Keep the line that returns the page and remove the line that returns the JSON.  Basically, pick one.

Comment: @WillBlack: *”maybe I need two functions”* - If you want to return two entirely different responses, yes.  And the client would make two requests to get those responses.

Answer (score 1):

The `res.json()` represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request. On the other hand, `res.sendFile()` transfers the file at the given path.

In both cases, the flow is essentially transferred to client who might have made the request.

So no, you cannot use `res.sendFile` and `res.json` together.

```
var options = {
    headers: {
        'name': 'user1',
    }
  };

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'), options);
```

Thats really the closest you can do to achieve the desired task.

Comment: Thank you. But how to get JSON? I need to create another adress may be '/users/data/' for it?

Comment: you can get user name from headers.

Comment: Custom headers like this would be pretty strange.  It works, but would quickly fall apart if the structure of the `users` object grows at all.  (The fact that `users` is an array of objects and not just a string value implies this possibility.)  Looking at the client-side code in the question, I'm curious why a file needs to be included in the response at all?  The code appears to just be reading the JSON data.